# Acesso MySQL através de cliente MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Antes de tudo gostaria de informar que meus conhecimentos em SQL é de iniciante...
Possuo um aplicativo cliente MSSQL proprietário e gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer com que ele acesse à banco de dados MySQL através de servidor lincado ou outra forma.
A estória é a seguinte:
Esse aplicativo proprietário acessa um servidor de banco de dados MSSQL que necessita ser trocado de host.
Estou estudando a possibilidade de comprar uma conta em um que possui apenas MySQL.

Realizei alguns testes:
Migrei a base de dados do MSSQL para MySQL através do Workbench do MySQL;
Linkei o servidor MySQL no MSSQL Studio 2012 e consegui fazer várias buscas no servidor MySQL conforme vários tutoriais disponíveis na internet;

Agora o aplicativo não enxerga a base de dados no MSSQL.
Eu estava pensando que o acesso a servidores lincados era transparente para os aplicativos clientes, que o servidor MSSQL mapeava todas as bases de dados existentes e realizava os Query´s à base correta.
Existe alguma forma de se fazer isso que eu desejo? Seja por alguma configuração ou por algum aplicativo que "emule" um servidor MSSQL em uma base de dados MySQL?

Agradeço antecipadamente a ajuda

Comment: Você pode realizar alterações no código deste aplicativo proprietário?

Comment: Pois é Cigano Morrison Mendez, esse é meu problema! Eu não posso alterar o código pois é um aplicativo comercial. Eu somente posso configurar o endereço do servidor MSSQL e a base de dados.

Comment: Como o aplicativo se conecta às bases? Pra funcionar, teria que ser um adaptador genérico, como um ODBC, senão não funcionará de forma alguma.

Comment: Ele se conecta pelo SQL Server. O aplicativo é todo para SQL Server da Microsoft eu estou tentando usar bases de dados MySQL mas de fato não sei se existe como.